# Auto Filled textbox in php

Tags: php, text, textbox, autofill

I am a beginner. 
I created a simple generator of pictures and I would like that when he was generate code in the text box and not as plain text. 
Please help.

So it should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXT7X.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are doing something like

```
echo $code;
```

to show your code; if this is the case so you only have to do it like this :

```
echo '<input type="text" name="my_code" value="' . $code . '">';
```

or

```
echo '<textarea name="my_code">' . $code . '</textarea>';
```

That's it

Answer (score 0):

Use basic `HTML` `FORM` elements with `readonly` attribute.

```
<textarea readonly><?php echo $code; ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep in mind that PHP generates HTML that the browser parses...

```
<input type="text" name="url" value="<?php echo htmlspeciachars($url,ENT_QUOTES); ?>">
```

its important to use ENT_QUOTES or some other kind of data filter to avoid XSS.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what i am saying but if you want to set the text inside the text input than you should use `value` element in input tag. For example your code should look like this :-

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $yourvalue;?>" />
```

Hope this works for you.